# An attempt to attach an auto-named database file after setup

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, installation

I get this error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file C:\Program Files (x86)\Default Company Name\EvidencaSetup\Prodaja.mdf failed. A database with the same name exists, or spicified file cannot be opene, or it is located on UNC share.

The database and everything works fine in Visual Studio. But after seting up the program, this error appears and nothing works. This is my first time using Visual Studio installer 2013 could the problem be the way I made the setup? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First check if a database with the same name `Prodaja` exists, then check if the specified file can be opened, then check if it located on a UNC share.

Comment: If you want to use the `AttachDbFileName=....` approach of SQL Server (which I strongly recommend ***NOT*** doing), then you **must have** SQL Server **EXPRESS** (no other edition!) installed on that machine where your app is about to run

Comment: The database is inside the visual studio project so it should exist. Im not really sure how to check if its located on a UNC share.